# Rspec for delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing specs for delete methods using rspec in rails.
My method is like this

```
   def destroy
     if @user.destroy
       json_response Hash({message: 'Successfully deleted'})
     elsif @user.present?
       json_response @user.errors.full_messages, :unprocessable_entity
     else
       json_response ["You can't delete it as it has been already deleted"], :unprocessable_entity
   end
```

My specs is like this and now I want to add for else condition.

```
describe "DELETE#destroy" do

it "Delete requeted user" do
  user = User.create! valid_attributes
  delete :destroy, params: {use_route: 'api/v1/', id: user.to_param}, format: :json
  return_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(return_response["message"]).to eq "Successfully deleted"
  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end

it "Can't delete the user as it's already deleted" do
  user = User.create! valid_attributes
  delete :destroy, params: {use_route: 'api/v1/', id: user.to_param}, format: :json
  delete :destroy, params: {use_route: 'api/v1/', id: user.to_param}, format: :json

  return_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

  expect(return_response[0]).to eq "You can't delete it as it has been already deleted"
  expect(response).to have_http_status(422)
end
```

end

When I am running specs, it's working fine. But when I am seeing coverage, t's not covering this conditions:

```
elsif @user.present?
       json_response @user.errors.full_messages, :unprocessable_entity
```

Could anyone please look into this.

Comment: Do you have any validation trigger before destroy?

Comment: @ Rajdeep ,Yes before destroy, I have added one validation.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
delete :destroy, params: { id: '' }, format: :json
```

It should be

```
delete :destroy, params: { id: user }, format: :json
```

That's why your `User` is not being found in controller.

Comment: After passing user id in params, I am getting error like this "expected the response to have status code :unprocessable_entity (422) but it was :ok (200)"

Comment: Apparently `@user.destroy` succeeded and returned truthy value. Not the scope of this question, with this fix, specs seem to be written correctly.

Comment: You have updated your question so it now is completely different question, right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your controller is doing exactly what I expect it to do. I am guessing that you are setting `@user` using `User.find(params[:id])`. This will cause the controller to return a `:not_found` error regardless of what input you give for id, as long as it is not a valid id. I think what you are wanting to test is the `else` block that returns the errors. In order to do this, you need to force the `destroy` operation to fail somehow. Without seeing your user model it is hard to tell if it is actually possible for the destroy method to not be successful.